# First person WASD controls

Tags: javascript, 3d, html5-canvas, controls, game-physics

I'm currently developing a 3d game and I'd like to implement a kind of first-person control using the **wasd**-keys.

My snippet below includes velocity, position and rotation where rotation stands for a value between `0` *and* `2*Math.PI`.

My question how to update my code to use the **w**-key to go "straight" based on the current rotation, the **d** key to go back no matter where I'm facing to, and so on.

I believe you got an idea what my problem is - I need some kind of approach how to implement **acceleration**!

Any help would be really appreciated.

```js
let speed = 0.01,
  maxSpeed = 0.01,
  friction = 0.91

let position = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
  },
  velocity = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
  },
  rotation = 0;


let update = () => {
  if (keyPressed("w") && velocity.z > -maxSpeed) velocity.z -= speed
  if (keyPressed("s") && velocity.z < maxSpeed) velocity.z += speed
  if (keyPressed("a") && velocity.x > -maxSpeed) velocity.x -= speed
  if (keyPressed("d") && velocity.x < maxSpeed) velocity.x += speed

  velocity.z *= friction
  velocity.x *= friction

  position.z += velocity.z * Math.sin(rotation) // this is
  position.x += velocity.x * Math.sin(rotation) // not working
}
```

Comment: How are you updating `rotation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fixed version:

```
position.z += velocity.z * Math.cos(rotation);
position.x += velocity.z * Math.sin(rotation); 
position.z -= velocity.x * Math.sin(rotation); 
position.x += velocity.x * Math.cos(rotation);
```

Click into snippet to transfer focus and then use `WSAD` keys

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.min.js">
</script><script>
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,innerWidth / innerHeight,0.01,1000);
camera.position.set(0, 3, 0);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(500, 100, 0x666666, 0x444444));

let speed = 0.1, maxSpeed = 0.1, friction = 0.91, 
    position = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
    velocity = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
    rotation = 0, keyPressed = {};

let update = () => {
    if (keyPressed["w"] && velocity.z > -maxSpeed) velocity.z -= speed;
    if (keyPressed["s"] && velocity.z < maxSpeed) velocity.z += speed;
    if (keyPressed["a"] && velocity.x > -maxSpeed) velocity.x -= speed;
    if (keyPressed["d"] && velocity.x < maxSpeed) velocity.x += speed;
    velocity.z *= friction;
    velocity.x *= friction;
    position.z += velocity.z * Math.cos(rotation);
    position.x += velocity.z * Math.sin(rotation); 
    position.z -= velocity.x * Math.sin(rotation); 
    position.x += velocity.x * Math.cos(rotation);
};

setInterval(update, 10);
requestAnimationFrame(render);
addEventListener('keydown', e => keyPressed[e.key] = true)
addEventListener('keyup', e => keyPressed[e.key] = false)
addEventListener('mousemove', e => rotation = e.x*Math.PI*2/innerWidth)
addEventListener('resize', e => renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight))  

function render() {
    camera.rotation.y = rotation;
    camera.position.x = position.x;
    camera.position.z = position.z;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
</script>
<style>body,canvas{overflow:hidden;margin:0;}</style>
```

Comment: Thanks but tbh your answer is not really matching since I got a single rotationY value - instead of theta, phi and so on. A breakdown would be great!

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Great answer!